# PySpark regex join

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe, that needs to be joined with another dataframe, based on a string column. For eg.

> (bob1, "a.b.*.c") (bob2, "a.b.c")

when joined with

> (tom1, "a.b.d.c") (tom2, "a.b.c")

on the second column (the pattern), should give: (bob1, tom1) (bob2, tom2). I understand this can be done using **rlike** but for for that I need to transform the pattern column into an actual regex. So

- **a.b.*.c** becomes **^a.b.(\w+).c$**
- **a.b.c** becomes **^a.b.c$**

Im having trouble doing this conversion. I tried using regex_replace(), but due to having \ in the output, it inserts \ twice instead of once.

Comment: In fact, this is an interesting scenario. I guess `*` may appear everywhere not only in the 3rd position, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Then I don't think there is a different way other than cartesian product. Unless if the datasets are relatively small. Then you can find the patterns from df1 and extract them (`df1.collect`). Apply the patterns to df2 by replacing `\w` with `*` and finally join them with inner join. But that has the drawback that you add complexity and extra action of course.

Comment: That's pretty smart! I just checked the production data, and in practice all the wildcards are appearing in the second place only. I might just use your approach!

Answer (score 2):

`regexp_replace` can be used:

```python
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("bob1", "a.b.*.d"),("bob2","a.b.c")], ["col1", "col2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("tom1", "a.b.c.d"),("tom2","a.b.c")], ["col3", "col4"])
df1 = df1.withColumn("join_col", F.concat(F.lit("^"), F.regexp_replace(F.col("col2"), "\\*", "(\\\\w+)"), F.lit("$")))
df_joined = df1.join(df2, F.expr("col4 rlike join_col"))
df_joined.show()
```

prints

```
+----+-------+-------------+----+-------+
|col1|   col2|     join_col|col3|   col4|
+----+-------+-------------+----+-------+
|bob1|a.b.*.d|^a.b.(\w+).d$|tom1|a.b.c.d|
|bob2|  a.b.c|      ^a.b.c$|tom2|  a.b.c|
+----+-------+-------------+----+-------+
```

The parentheses around `\w+` could be omitted.

Unfortunately, `df_joined.explain()` shows that the `rlike` join causes a CartesianProduct:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CartesianProduct col4#5 RLIKE join_col#26
:- *(1) Project [col1#0, col2#1, concat(^, regexp_replace(col2#1, \*, (\\w+)), $) AS join_col#26]
:  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(concat(^, regexp_replace(col2#1, \*, (\\w+)), $))
:     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col1#0,col2#1]
+- *(2) Filter isnotnull(col4#5)
   +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[col3#4,col4#5]
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! CartesianProduct is to be expected here, but one side of the join in my case is really small compared to the other so im not that worried

Comment: Also, `broacasting` the small df, it could be helpful here.

Comment: I realised both the dataframes are relatively small. One is ~1gb and the other is ~100mb. I just collected the dataframe and replaced all the logic with pure python code and it runs pretty fast. Takes like 10 seconds to do the job. I think I don't even need to read the file using spark, I'll just read it in the driver using python code.

Comment: Also using pandas it could even faster @Dexter :)